# Concept of work done by torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, torque

I know the derivation of work done by torque. But all I'm curious to know is when is WORK DONE BY A TORQUE positive and when is it NEGATIVE?

Comment: It is positive when it increases the energy of the object and negative when it decreases the energy of the object, just like all kinds of work.

Comment: So just like before, I just see if the force is opposite to the displacement and if it is its negative and if it isnt its posiitve. And then its magnitude is given by integral from (theta1) to (theta2) Torque d(theta)? Is there a way i can analyse its sign from the integral. Like for work by force it depends on dot product of F and dr and hence depends on their directions as i stated above

Comment: Torque and angular displacement are vectors, and the work is their dot product, just the same as "for work by force".

Comment: You open a door - positive work my torque. You stop a rotating door - negative work by torque.

Answer (score 2):

- Think of positive work as energy **added**. Positive work in the rotational sense is for example speeding up a bike wheel.
- Think of negative work as energy **taken away**. Negative work as before then for example slowing down a rotating bike wheel.

Positive means **added**. In the same way that positive *heat* means thermal energy **added**.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a point *A* riding on a moving rigid body. A force $\vec{F}_A$ is applied to this point, whilst it is moving with velocity $\vec{v}_A$. A torque $\vec{\tau}$ is applied to the rigid body and the body is rotating with $\vec{\omega}$.

The power exerted by the force and torque is

$$ P = \vec{F}_A \cdot \vec{v}_A + \vec{\tau} \cdot \vec{\omega} $$

if power $P$ is positive then the loading is doing work. If the point *A* is not moving, or there is no force applied, the power is just $\vec{\tau} \cdot \vec{\omega}$ and that is how you can tell if the work is done positive or negative.

<sub>Here $\cdot$ is the vector dot or the inner product.</sub>